# Is there a proper way to pass the active visual state of a ControlTemplate down into the DataTemplate?

Tags: xaml, uwp

When styling controls that have a `ContentPresenter` (like `GridViewItem`), and it has a bunch of visual states like `Focused`, `Unfocused`, `PointerFocused`, `Disabled` etc. Is there a proper way to pass the active visual state down through to the `DataTemplate`? IOW, is there a nice way for any UI in the `DataTemplate` to react to the same visual states as its parent (`GridViewItem` as an example, but would want a solution for any `ControlTemplate` that uses a `ContentPresenter` really)? Ex)

```
<DataTemplate>
    <UserControl>
        <Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup>
                    <!-- These states are copied from the ControlTemplate,
                    but obviously don't work by default. -->
                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="foo.Fill" Value="Red" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <Rectangle x:Name="foo" />
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

My initial naive approach would be to extend `ContentPresenter` and add a custom property like `ActiveVisualState` then call `VisualStateManager.GoToState((Control)contentPresentorChild, ActiveVisualState, true);`. Then use that presenter in the `GridViewItem` template style (or whatever control I was styling). But I feel like there should be a better, more natural and not so specific, way to achieve this.

Comment: I'm confused about your description, could you please detail it? Firstly, the `VisualStateManager` inside `GridViewItem` is for the root `Grid` of `ControlTemplate`, not `ConentPresenter` .  Secondly, what is "pass the active visual state down" mean? Thirdly, for "pass it down into its Content", what is the content here?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT added some detail. 1) I'm not suggesting `VisualStateManager ` is for `ContentPresenter`...sorry for the confusion. 2) Clarified (I hope). 3) Clarified (I hope).

Answer (score 0):

We cannot see where you put your ContentPresenter and we also cannot see where you modified your template. So it's not clear what you want.

But if your simply want to modify a property value based on different state. why not just change the status from the setter like this:

```
       <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="NameofYourContentPresenter.(UIElement.Opacity)"
                    Value="0.5" />
        </VisualState.Setters>
```

For customized property you just need to specify it from your XAML.

Comment: I didn't put template code in because that's sort of what I'm asking about. If there's a way for the content in DataTemplate to react to its container's (ex. GridViewItem) visual states (ex. Disabled or any other visual state) without having to modify GridViewItem's default template, then great! Would love to know that solution. If I have to modify the container's template (the naive approach I specified in the question uses this approach, but it doesn't seem like the best solution. I'll update the questions with it anyway), then would like to know that solution.

Comment: Also worth noting is that the reason why I want to pass the visual state down, as opposed to just changing a property on the top-level content (like what you're doing with `<Setter Target="NameofYourContentPresenter.(UIElement.Opacity)" Value="0.5" />`), is that I only want to update properties on certain child elements inside the DataTemplate.